# Returning SetConsoleTextAttribute colour value from function in c

Tags: c, function, winapi, colors

Currently im trying to call a function to change the color the text background using the windows.h functions to do so. I have done it before but not from another function. Is the problem that the function needs to return the color value somehow or there is just something wrong.
The function was called from another function if that changes anything.

Code Together:

```
void setColour(HANDLE* hConsole, int ChangeColour, int Red, int Green, int Blue, int Colour) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);
    info.ColorTable[ChangeColour] = RGB(Red, Green, Blue);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, Colour);
}

void mainMenu(WindowProp* Dimensions, HANDLE* hConsole) {
    getWindowSize(Dimensions);
    clearScreen();
    setColour(hConsole, 3, 120, 120, 236, 48);
    printf("Set");
    int DisplayRowCount, DisplayColumnCount;
    for (DisplayRowCount = 0; DisplayRowCount <= Dimensions->Y-1; DisplayRowCount++) {
        for (DisplayColumnCount = 0; DisplayColumnCount <= Dimensions->X-1; DisplayColumnCount++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

mainMenu called from main:

```
mainMenu(&WindowP, hConsole);
```

Comment: You are passing a `HANDLE*` pointer to `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx()` and `SetConsoleTextAttribute()`, but they expect a `HANDLE` value instead. `HANDLE` is already a pointer type, so there is no need to pass it around by address. The only way your code could compile is if you are compiling without `STRICT` defined, so `HANDLE` maps to `void*` (`STRICT` would have caught this error and failed to compile). You need to change your `HANDLE*` parameters to `HANDLE` and pass them around by value instead of by pointer

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok so i fixed that and the function gets called properly but the color still isn't changing

Comment: Well, you are retrieving *a copy* of the console's color table and then altering that copy, but you are not assigning the alterations back to the console with `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx()`. And `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` only affects higher-level output functions, like `WriteFile()`, not lower-level output functions, like `WriteConsoleOutput()`, `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()`, etc. Check your RTL's implementation of `printf()` to see what API function is actually used for console output. And, you are not checking either API function for failures.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got it fixed. I first decided to declare the HANDLE value in the mainMenu() function and remove the HANDLE pointer.

Secondly, the setColour() function's GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx() did get called before changing the color values but wasn't called after modifying the color values thus i needed to call GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx() a second time to get the new color values to use.

Fixed Code:

```
void setColour(HANDLE* hConsole, int ChangeColour, int Red, int Green, int Blue, int Colour) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);
    info.ColorTable[ChangeColour] = RGB(Red, Green, Blue);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, Colour);
}

void mainMenu(WindowProp* Dimensions) {
    getWindowSize(Dimensions);
    clearScreen();
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    setColour(hConsole, 3, 120, 120, 236, 48);
    int DisplayRowCount, DisplayColumnCount;
    for (DisplayRowCount = 0; DisplayRowCount <= Dimensions->Y-1; DisplayRowCount++) {
        for (DisplayColumnCount = 0; DisplayColumnCount <= Dimensions->X-1; DisplayColumnCount++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}
```